# pso algorithm on test function. But I'm stuck with python code

Tags: python, shift, particle-swarm

So I have to classes Swarm and Particles, and a class for Sphere function.
But when I'm trying to run the optimization, I get error on iteretation and I don't understand why:

*TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'*

Eventually, if you can give me some tipf for shifted sphere function.

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

import numpy
import numpy.random

from particle import Particle

class Swarm (object):

```
__metaclass__ = ABCMeta

def __init__ (self, 
        swarmsize, 
        minvalues, 
        maxvalues, 
        currentVelocityRatio,
        localVelocityRatio, 
        globalVelocityRatio):
    
    self.__swarmsize = swarmsize

    assert len (minvalues) == len (maxvalues)
    assert (localVelocityRatio + globalVelocityRatio) > 4

    self.__minvalues = numpy.array (minvalues[:])
    self.__maxvalues = numpy.array (maxvalues[:])

    self.__currentVelocityRatio = currentVelocityRatio
    self.__localVelocityRatio = localVelocityRatio
    self.__globalVelocityRatio = globalVelocityRatio

    self.__globalBestFinalFunc = None
    self.__globalBestPosition = None

    self.__swarm = self.__createSwarm ()


def __getitem__ (self, index):
    """
    Возвращает частицу с заданным номером
    """
    return self.__swarm[index]


def __createSwarm (self):
    
    return [Particle (self) for _ in range (self.__swarmsize) ]



def nextIteration (self):
    
    for particle in self.__swarm:
        return particle.nextIteration (self)


@property
def minvalues (self):
    return self.__minvalues


@property
def maxvalues (self):
    return self.__maxvalues


@property
def currentVelocityRatio (self):
    return self.__currentVelocityRatio


@property
def localVelocityRatio (self):
    return self.__localVelocityRatio


@property
def globalVelocityRatio (self):
    return self.__globalVelocityRatio


@property
def globalBestPosition (self):
    return self.__globalBestPosition


@property
def globalBestFinalFunc (self):
    return self.__globalBestFinalFunc


def getFinalFunc (self, position):
    assert len (position) == len (self.minvalues)

    finalFunc = self._finalFunc (position)

    if (self.__globalBestFinalFunc == None or
            finalFunc < self.__globalBestFinalFunc):
        self.__globalBestFinalFunc = finalFunc
        self.__globalBestPosition = position[:]


@abstractmethod
def _finalFunc (self, position):
    pass


@property
def dimension (self):
    
    return len (self.minvalues)


def _getPenalty (self, position, ratio):
    
    penalty1 = sum ([ratio * abs (coord - minval)
        for coord, minval in zip (position, self.minvalues) 
        if coord < minval ] )

    penalty2 = sum ([ratio * abs (coord - maxval)
        for coord, maxval in zip (position, self.maxvalues) 
        if coord > maxval ] )

    return penalty1 + penalty2
```

class Particle (object):

```
def __init__ (self, swarm):
    
    self.__currentPosition = self.__getInitPosition (swarm)

   
    self.__localBestPosition = self.__currentPosition[:]

    self.__localBestFinalFunc = swarm.getFinalFunc (self.__currentPosition)

    self.__velocity = self.__getInitVelocity (swarm)


@property
def position (self):
    return self.__currentPosition


@property
def velocity (self):
    return self.__velocity


def __getInitPosition (self, swarm):
    return numpy.random.rand (swarm.dimension) * (swarm.maxvalues - swarm.minvalues) + swarm.minvalues


def __getInitVelocity (self, swarm):
    
    assert len (swarm.minvalues) == len (self.__currentPosition)
    assert len (swarm.maxvalues) == len (self.__currentPosition)

    minval = -(swarm.maxvalues - swarm.minvalues)
    maxval = (swarm.maxvalues - swarm.minvalues)

    return numpy.random.rand (swarm.dimension) * (maxval - minval) + minval


def nextIteration (self, swarm):
    
    rnd_currentBestPosition = numpy.random.rand (swarm.dimension)

    rnd_globalBestPosition = numpy.random.rand (swarm.dimension)

    veloRatio = swarm.localVelocityRatio + swarm.globalVelocityRatio
    commonRatio = (2.0 * swarm.currentVelocityRatio / 
            (numpy.abs (2.0 - veloRatio - numpy.sqrt (veloRatio ** 2 - 4.0 * veloRatio) ) ) )

  
    newVelocity_part1 = commonRatio * self.__velocity

    newVelocity_part2 = (commonRatio * 
            swarm.localVelocityRatio * 
            rnd_currentBestPosition * 
            (self.__localBestPosition - self.__currentPosition) )

    newVelocity_part3 = (commonRatio * 
            swarm.globalVelocityRatio * 
            rnd_globalBestPosition * 
            (swarm.globalBestPosition - self.__currentPosition) )
    
    self.__velocity = newVelocity_part1 + newVelocity_part2 + newVelocity_part3

    self.__currentPosition += self.__velocity

    finalFunc = swarm.getFinalFunc (self.__currentPosition)
    if finalFunc < self.__localBestFinalFunc:
        self.__localBestPosition = self.__currentPosition[:]
        self.__localBestFinalFunc = finalFunc
```

class Swarm_X2 (Swarm):
def **init** (self,
swarmsize,
minvalues,
maxvalues,
currentVelocityRatio,
localVelocityRatio,
globalVelocityRatio):
Swarm.**init** (self,
swarmsize,
minvalues,
maxvalues,
currentVelocityRatio,
localVelocityRatio,
globalVelocityRatio)

```
def _finalFunc (self, position):
    penalty = self._getPenalty (position, 10000.0)
    finalfunc = sum (position * position)

    return finalfunc + penalty
```

from swarm_x2 import Swarm_X2
from utils import printResult

if **name** == "**main**":
iterCount = 300

```
dimension = 5
swarmsize = 200

minvalues = numpy.array ([-100] * dimension)
maxvalues = numpy.array ([100] * dimension)

currentVelocityRatio = 0.1
localVelocityRatio = 1.0
globalVelocityRatio = 5.0

swarm = Swarm_X2 (swarmsize, 
        minvalues, 
        maxvalues,
        currentVelocityRatio,
        localVelocityRatio, 
        globalVelocityRatio
        )

for n in range (iterCount):
    print "Position", swarm[0].position
    print "Velocity", swarm[0].velocity

    print printResult (swarm, n)

    swarm.nextIteration()
```